# Enable WYSIWYG for a custom textarea form field in opencart

Tags: php, wysiwyg, opencart, custom-fields

This is an opencart administration question.

I have created a custom field (textarea) in the "general-tab", for products. Does any body have a quick fix to turn this into the wysiwyg editor used in the "Description" field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before footer add ckeditor.js file and code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
<?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
CKEDITOR.replace('description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>'
}); 
<?php } ?>
//--></script>
```

Replace:

```
 description<?php echo $language['language_id'];
```

with id of the textarea.